# sub gradient of Moreau envelope

Tags: analysis, optimization, convex-analysis

Is there an equality formula for the subgradients of the Moreau envelope,
$$e_f(x) = \inf_z \frac{1}{2}||x-z||_2^2 + f(z),$$
 of a lsc (lower semicontinuous) and proper function $f:\mathbb{R}^p \to \mathbb{R}$?
Expressing $e_f(x)$ as the difference of two convex functions $$e_f(x) = \frac{1}{2}||x||_2^2 - (f+\frac{1}{2}||\cdot||_2^2)^*(x),$$
it is well known that $\partial e_f(x) \subset x - P_f(x)$,
where
$$
P_f(x) = {\arg \min}_z \frac{1}{2}||x-z||_2^2 + f(z),
$$
is the proximal map of $f$ (it  maybe  multivalued, take for example the hard thresholding proximal map).

Is Proposition 1.107 from 'Boris.S.Mordukovich -  Variational analysis and Generalized differentiation' p.112 an answer to my question?

Thanks in advance,
Alex

Comment: Not a real answer to your question, and possibly too restrictive an assumption, but it covers most cases: if $f$ is _prox-regular_ then for sufficiently small $\gamma>0$ you have that $e_{\gamma f}$ is actually differentiable and equality $\nabla e_{\gamma f}(x) = x - P_{\gamma f}(x)$ holds. Prox-regularity was introduced in [Poliquin, Rockafellar - 1994](http://www.math.washington.edu/~rtr/papers/rtr157-ProxRegular.pdf) and has been studied a lot ever since.

Comment: You can find the proof of such claim for prox-regular functions on [2011 Rockafellar and Wets, Variational Analysis](http://www.math.washington.edu/~rtr/papers/rtr169-VarAnalysis-RockWets.pdf) Proposition 13.37 page 617.